# Where do I get the key for the first house?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've 'completed' the game, but didn't find the key for the first house. (I got the one for the arcade machine house). Where can I find it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dude I've been searching for hours. I've went through the savegame code file and nothing. I've searched that for "house" for "key" and for "false" and checked every single one and nothing was a match to it.

My only conclusion  SO FAR is that there is no way to open this door.

I'm gonna run through the source code now to see if there is anything about that or the hidden commands that the computer tells us about and I'll edit this later.

**EDIT**

Found in the code:

```
Village.prototype.goToFirstHouse = function () {
    alert("yay");
};
```

While the other houses call for a function named setPlace

```
this.getGame().setPlace(new SecondHouse(this.getGame()));
```

The first house only does an alert. Which means there is nothing there and even if we managed to 'enter' the first house we'd only get an alert saying "yay", nothing else. So there is nothing in the first house 8D