# Opening the door to the first house on the left in the village in Candy Box 2

Tags: candy-box-2

I want to know what is inside, but I don't know how to open the door! How can I open it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I get the key for the first house?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137220/where-do-i-get-the-key-for-the-first-house)